azure function not working on local machine after upgrading to Azure.Identity package
I have an azure function which uses old nuget packages. Today when I removed the old one and replace with Azure.Identity, and this code triggers error when running my code in Visual studio:
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultName))
{
    configurationBuilder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
    keyVaultUri,
    new DefaultAzureCredential());
};

//base.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder);
Configuration = configurationBuilder.ConfigurationBuilder.Build();

Error:
EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
If I directly pass Visual Studio Credential, it works fine. However, in the old nuget package AspNetCore.Configuration.Secret, passing DefaultAzureCredential works on problem in my visual studio or production environment
configurationBuilder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
    keyVaultUri,
    new VisualStudioCredential());

So is there a way to get this work like before, or I have to do some walkaround like if (localenvironment)-> VisualStudioCredential else ->DefaultAzureCredential?

Have you added Azure AD credentials in the System Environment variables?


EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.

The error occurs because the correct DefaultAzureCredentials are not set in the environment variables. You need to add the following to the System Environment Variables as shown below.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
AZURE_TENANT_ID


Below is a sample HTTP trigger function to retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using DefaultAzureCredential from the Azure.Identity library.
Code :
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
public static class KeyVaultFunction
{
    [FunctionName("KeyVaultSecret")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> KeyVaultSecret(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
            var kvUri = "https://<KeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net/";
 
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secretName = "<secretName>";
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
 
            string KVsecret = secret.Value.Value;
            return new OkObjectResult(KVsecret);
    }
}

Terminal Output :

Browser Output :
I successfully retrieved the secret from Azure Key Vault in the browser.

